# jQuery: How to stop a helper from being removed if it wasn't successfully dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a [`draggable`](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) with a custom [`helper`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper). Sometimes the helper is a clone and sometimes it is the original element.

The problem is that when the helper is the original element and is **not** dropped on a valid droppable it gets removed. My solution looks like this so far:

in my `on_dropped` callback I set `ui.helper.dropped_on_droppable` to `true`;

In the `stop` callback of the draggable, I check for that variable and then ... what do I do?

```
$('.my_draggable').draggable({
    stop   : function(e, ui) {
        if (!ui.helper.dropped_on_droppable) {
            /* what do I do here? */
        }
    },
```

Is this even the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution! It's ugly and it breaks the 'rules of encapsulation,' but at least it does the job.

Remember **this is just for special cases**! jQuery can handle its own helper removal just fine. In my case I had a helper that was sometimes the original element and sometimes a clone, so it wasn't always appropriate to delete the helper after reverting.

```
element.draggable({
    stop   : function(e, ui) {
        /* "dropped_on_droppable" is custom and set in my custom drop method
           ".moved_draggable" is custom and set in my custom drag method, 
                     to differentiate between the two types of draggables
        */               
        if (!ui.helper.dropped_on_droppable & ui.helper.hasClass('moved_draggable')) {
            /* this is the big hack that breaks encapsulation */
            $.ui.ddmanager.current.cancelHelperRemoval = true;
        }
    },
```

### Warning: this breaks encapsulation and may not be forwards compatible

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here, but is it not simply a case of adding

```
revert: "invalid"
```

to the options of the draggable if the draggable is of an original element, not a clone?

Comment: No, jquery still automatically deletes the helper after reverting. I finally found a workaround at least....

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom helper that aggregates multiple-selection draggables into a single div. This does not seem to jive with the revert functionality so I came up with this scheme. The elements are manually appended back to the original parent which I keep track of via .data().

```
.draggable({
    helper: function() {
        var div = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .data('lastParent', $(this).parent());
        return div;
    },
    start: function() {
        //... add multiple selection items to the helper..          
    },
    stop: function(event,ui) {
        $( $(ui.helper).data('lastParent') ).append( $(ui.helper).children() );
    }
}
```

This approach does lose out on the pretty animation, but it may be useful to you or someone else with this issue.